# Transitive tournament

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> 1.) Prove that a tournament (i.e., an orientation of $K_n$) is a transitive tournament if and only if it does not have any directed cycles of length $3$.
>
> 2.) Prove that a tournament is strongly connected if and only if it has a directed Hamiltonian cycle.

I tried this for Question 2. If $G$ has a directed Hamilton cycle (thus a directed closed walk containing every vertex at least once), then $G$ is strongly connected. The converse that $G$ has direct Hamiltonian cycle assuming that $G$ is strongly connected. Since $G$ is a tournament, then it implies there is an open Hamiltonian path. I do not know where to continue from here.. Can anyone help me prove it? I would appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your thoughts on the problem and we will be happy to help. Also, please use MathJax formatting. I've edited your post to include it.

Comment: @ml0105 Thanks for the correction. I tried this for Question 2.

If G has a directed Hamilton cycle (thus a directed closed walk containing every vertex at least once), then G is strongly connected. 

The converse that G has direct Hamiltonian cycle assuming that G is strongly connected. Since G is a tournament, then it implies there is an open Hamiltonian path. I do not know where to continue from here....

Comment: I don't see any link or work. Can you please include it?

Comment: Important: a Hamiltonian cycle does not visit every vertex *at least* once, it visits every vertex *exactly* once.

Comment: @JackM... Thanks for correcting me. But how do I continue from there...

Answer (score 2):

Let's call your tournament $T$, and write $a \rightarrow b$ when there is an arc from $a$ to $b$.  Write $a \rightarrow B$ when $B$ is a vertex set and $a$ has an arc to all members of $B$.  Finally write $B \rightarrow a$ when all members of a set $B$ have an arc to $a$.

1) is straightforward enough.  If $T$ has a cycle of length 3, then it can't be transitive by definition.  Conversely, suppose $T$ is not transitive.  Then $\forall a,b,c \in V(T) [a \rightarrow b, b \rightarrow c \Rightarrow a \rightarrow  c]$ is false.  What do you get by negating this expression ?

2) There's probably a better way for the tougher direction, but here goes.  One way is to suppose $T$ has no Hamiltonian cycle and get that $T$ is not strongly connected.  Let $C = c_1c_2 \ldots c_k c_1$ be a directed cycle of $T$ with the largest number of vertices.

Let $x \in V(T)$ such that $x \notin C$.  If $c_i \rightarrow x$ for some $c_i \in C$, then $c_{i + 1} \rightarrow x$ as otherwise, $x \rightarrow c_{i+1}$ and $C' = c_1c_2 \ldots c_i x c_{i + 1} \ldots c_k c_1$ would be a bigger cycle (but $C$ is a largest cycle by assumption).  Applying this reasoning inductively, we have that $C \rightarrow x$ when some $c_i \rightarrow x$.

So what do you get for any $x$ outside $C$ ?  Either $C \rightarrow x$ or $x \rightarrow C$.  Let $X = \{x : C \rightarrow x\}$ and $Y = \{y : y \rightarrow C\}$.
Take $x \in X, y \in Y$.  If $x \rightarrow y$, then you can extend the $C$ cycle by deviating with $c_ixyc_{i + 1}$.  So $y \rightarrow x$, for all $x \in X, y \in Y$.  From this, you can deduce that there is no way to go from $x \in X$ to $c_i \in C$, hence $T$ is not strongly connected.

What's left for you to do is to argue that $C$ exists, and handle the cases when $X$ or $Y$ is empty (and tell us why both can't be empty).

Comment: many thanks. this came in really handle.